# match_parent is not working in custom toolbar

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-linearlayout, toolbar, android-layout-weight

I have made custom toolbar with search and setting icon . when i click on search icon edittext should apper with match_parent and should occupy available space till the search icon . However it is not happening . it just appear with very small space at the top-left side . Please help where i am wrong

[image]

I would like to share my whole code with xml

main_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#DCDCDC"
android:padding="0dp"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="myresolver.faisal.home.com.myresolver.MainActivity">

<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    layout="@layout/my_toolbar"></include>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:weightSum="4"

        >


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="3">

            <ImageView
                style="@style/icon"
                android:background="@drawable/fear_96" />

            <ImageView
                style="@style/icon"
                android:background="@drawable/fear_96"></ImageView>

            <ImageView
                style="@style/icon"
                android:background="@drawable/fear_96" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="3">

            <ImageView
                style="@style/icon"
                android:background="@drawable/fear_96" />

            <ImageView
                style="@style/icon"
                android:background="@drawable/fear_96" />

            <ImageView
                style="@style/icon"
                android:background="@drawable/fear_96" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="3">

            <ImageView
                style="@style/icon"
                android:background="@drawable/fear_96" />

            <ImageView
                style="@style/icon"
                android:background="@drawable/fear_96" />

            <ImageView
                style="@style/icon"
                android:background="@drawable/fear_96" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="3">

            <ImageView
                style="@style/icon"
                android:background="@drawable/fear_96" />

            <ImageView
                style="@style/icon"
                android:background="@drawable/fear_96" />

            <ImageView
                style="@style/icon"
                android:background="@drawable/fear_96" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="3">

            <ImageView
                style="@style/icon"
                android:background="@drawable/fear_96" />

            <ImageView
                style="@style/icon"
                android:background="@drawable/fear_96" />

            <ImageView
                style="@style/icon"
                android:background="@drawable/fear_96" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="3">

            <ImageView
                style="@style/icon"
                android:background="@drawable/fear_96" />

            <ImageView
                style="@style/icon"
                android:background="@drawable/fear_96" />

            <ImageView
                style="@style/icon"
                android:background="@drawable/fear_96" />
        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
   </ScrollView>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

mytoolbar.xml

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/orange"
    app:titleTextColor="@color/white"></android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>`

my main_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<item
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp"
    android:id="@+id/search"
    ></item>
<item
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/setting"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_white_24dp"
    android:id="@+id/setting"></item>
</menu>
```

my search_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/searchEditText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"   // THIS IS NOT WORKING
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
    android:inputType="text" />

</LinearLayout>
```

My activity

```
EditText searchEditText;
boolean isSearchBoxOpen = false;
Toolbar toolbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);


    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.search:
            onSearchedHandler();
            break;

        case R.id.setting:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Setting is UnderConstruction", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
    }


    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void onSearchedHandler() {
    if (isSearchBoxOpen) {

        String word = searchEditText.getText().toString();

        if (word != null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Searching for ..." + word, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } else {

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.search_layout);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        searchEditText = (EditText) actionBar.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.searchEditText);

        searchEditText.requestFocus();
        InputMethodManager keyboard = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        keyboard.showSoftInput(searchEditText, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);


        isSearchBoxOpen = true;

    }

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    if (isSearchBoxOpen) {

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        isSearchBoxOpen = false;

        return;

    }

    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: linear layout width at search_layout should be wrap content

Comment: I didnt understood what are you saying ?

Comment: search_layout.xml  ->linear layout height should be wrap_content

Comment: I tried .but its not working

Comment: try removing scrollview android:fillViewport="true"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When the custom view is inflated as a result of calling setCustomView(resId), wrap_content is forced upon it (if you look into the view dump, you can see that the wrapping LinearLayout is shrunk, not the EditText).
You can set the custom view in the following way:

```
    View customView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.search_layout, null);
    ActionBar.LayoutParams params = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    actionBar.setCustomView(customView, params);
```

Comment: Thanks alot brother . I was looking for it from two days . finally its working fine. You explained it really well whats was the actuall problem . I was desperately looking for it . And it increase my knowledge . Thanks again

Answer (score 15):

Use the below code for toolbar xlm layout :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:app="schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/primaryColor"
    android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    android:contentInsetRight="0dp"
    android:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
    app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
    app:contentInsetEnd="0dp" />
```

Comment: Thanks! Good for me!

Comment: the `contentInset` properties helped me. awesome code!

Answer (score 1):

just add this line to take full width

`app:contentInsetStart="0dp"`

Answer (score 0):

The padding in the RelativeLayout in main_activity.xml is preventing it from taking the full space so instead of having

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#DCDCDC"
android:padding="0dp"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="myresolver.faisal.home.com.myresolver.MainActivity">
```

you move the paddings to the scrollview such that

```
<ScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:fillViewport="true">
```

Comment: @FaisalAhmed what is it giving you ?

Comment: scroll view with padding from all side .And edittext as it was. No change

Comment: Wrap the relative layout and custom bar layout with a liear layout